# Adding Dividers

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I currently have a Storedproc t hat is returning values for me to bind with a gridview in asp.net.  One thing I want to do is combine two fields into one seperated by a / but I cannot seem to get this working.

Here is my stored proc

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX);

BEGIN
SET @SQL = N'SELECT SYSTEM AS ''System''
            , ENTN AS ''Entity''
            , MED_CTR AS ''Medical Center''
            , MED_CTR_LEVEL AS ''Medical Center Level''
            , DEPT_ID AS ''Department ID''
    FROM V_ROLLUP_SYSTEM_DESC_REV1
    WHERE (DEPT_ID = '+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@DEPTCODE)+')
        AND SYSTEM IN ('+@SYS+')'
PRINT(@SQL)
EXEC(@SQL)
```

So I want to combine MED_CTR with MED_CTR_LEVEL seperated by a "/" and labeled as Medical Center/ Level.  I cant seem to combine it thus far since every method I have tried to add a "/" in it has returned me nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SET @SQL = N'SELECT SYSTEM AS [System]
            , ENTN AS [Entity]
            , (MED_CTR +''/''+ MED_CTR_LEVEL) as [Medical Center/ Level]
            , DEPT_ID AS [Department ID]
    FROM V_ROLLUP_SYSTEM_DESC_REV1
    WHERE (DEPT_ID = '+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@DEPTCODE)+')
        AND SYSTEM IN ('+@SYS+')'
```

And if you want to make sure the concat of the 2 columns always succeeds, you can do this:

```
SET @SQL = N'SELECT SYSTEM AS [System]
            , ENTN AS [Entity]
            , ISNULL(MED_CTR,''N/A'') +''/''+ ISNULL(MED_CTR_LEVEL,''N/A'') ) as [Medical Center/ Level]
            , DEPT_ID AS [Department ID]
    FROM V_ROLLUP_SYSTEM_DESC_REV1
    WHERE (DEPT_ID = '+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@DEPTCODE)+')
        AND SYSTEM IN ('+@SYS+')'
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it does not do what I want it to do.  That gives me the result of MEDY instead of MED / Y or MED/Y

Comment: @user1512593 When you concatenate 2 columns and one of them is `NULL`, the whole result will be `NULL`; by adding `isnull(column,'N/A')` I make sure that for null values on either one, the result would be `N/A/Y` or `N/A/N/A` or `Some value/N/A`